# gdal_calc.py - How to correctly use numpy.any()?

Tags: python, numpy

I have R, G, B bands in separate tif files. Each file has mask, where no data value is 0.
Following command does the work:

```
gdal_calc.py -A red.tif --A_band=2 -B green.tif --B_band=2 -C blue.tif --C_band=2 --outfile=mask.tif --calc="255*logical_or(logical_or(A==0,B==0),C==0)" --NoDataValue=255
```

However, I can have more bands and I want to generate command dynamically using numpy.any():

```
gdal_calc.py -A red.tif --A_band=2 -B green.tif --B_band=2 -C blue.tif --C_band=2 --outfile=mask.tif --calc="255*any([A==0,B==0,C==0])" --NoDataValue=255
```

However, it seems that any() always returns True and mask.tif has all pixels of value 255. I want to use value of 255 for mask, since 255*(true/false) is 0/255 opposite to 0*(true/false) is always 0.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

By [dnalow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3964322/dnalow) comment I added axis parameter with 0 and command works correctly:

```
gdal_calc.py -A red.tif --A_band=2 -B green.tif --B_band=2 -C blue.tif --C_band=2 --outfile=mask.tif --calc="255*any([A==0,B==0,C==0],axis=0)" --NoDataValue=255
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but I think you want to perform the `any` operation only along a certain (the zero-th) dimension, so try: `"255*any([A==0,B==0,C==0], axis=0)"`

Comment: Adding axis parameter is solution, thank you very much. However, when I tried any function without axis param via python command line with different values, I got correct results. In gdal_calc.py it created mask with all pixels of value 255 (any returned always true).

Comment: This might depend on whether you use a python builtin function (sum, max, min, any, all etc.) or the corresponding numpy or pylab functions (np.sum, np.max, ....etc.). If you mess up your namespace (`from numpy import *`, (avoid it)) than all these functions are overwritten and their behavior changes. That the `axis` argument is valid indicates that it is the np.any function.